# Concentration inequality for average of random vectors

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$ follow some distribution $q$; say $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = \mu.$ You can assume that the $X_i$ are bounded (i.e. $q$ has bounded support).

Is there some concentration result to bound the norm of $$\left|\left|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \mu \right| \right|_2?$$ In one dimension this is a simple application of something like the McDiarmid's Inequality, and I was wondering if this generalizes well to higher dimensions.

One thing you can do is just try to use McDiarmid's Inequality with the function $f(X_1, \dots, X_n) = \left|\left| \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu) \right| \right|_2$. However, that would give you a bound on $$\mathbb{P}\left( \left|\left| \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu) \right| \right|_2 - \mathbb{E}\left[\left|\left| \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu) \right| \right|_2 \right] > t \right),$$ which isn't quite what I want since then you would have to compute $\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\left| \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu) \right| \right|_2 \right]$.

I didn't find anything online, which makes me think that maybe this is difficult? Also, I know that you can just bound each coordinate separately and then union bound over the dimension, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this (a) without explicit dependence on the dimension and (b) maybe getting a bound in terms of the diameter of the support of $X$.

Comment: it's answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334335/lipschitz-function-of-independent-subgaussian-random-variables?noredirect=1&lq=1